# How can I assign the F3 access key to a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a `JFrame` as the main container of my application. And many `JInternalFrame` windows accordingly to their respectively functionality.

How can I assign a F3 acces key to a `JButton` placed inside a `JInternalFrame`?

Comment: *"How can I assign a F3 acces key to a `JButton` placed inside a `JInternalFrame`?"* The same way you'd do it for a button in an applet. (i.e. both the `JFrame` and `JInternalFrame` are largely irrelevant to the actual task.)

Comment: Normally you would use a mnemonic for the button so that the text is underlined which is a self documenting feature so the user knows what key to use. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons]() for more information and working examples. Otherwise you would need to use `Key Bindings`. The tutorial also has a section on key bindings.